# Jquery Waypoint with nested div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LzMja/4/)

I'm trying to get Waypoint working in a nested div but unable to do so.

I've `outer div` with fixed height. Inside that div, I have an `inner div` and an `Waypoint div`. Please find below the code.

**Html**

```
<div style="background:grey;height:300px;overflow:auto;">
    <div style="height:900px;background:#F5F6CE;"></div>
    <div id="waypoint" style="background:#B45F04;">Waypoint</div>    
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    console.log('Reached waypoint.');
}, {
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

The text *Reached waypoint.* is never printed in the console. Any pointers.?

*Edit: Updated the Fiddle.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The plugin documentation](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs) suggests that the default "viewport" (as it calls it) is the `window` object:

```
$.fn.waypoint.defaults = {
  context: window,
  ...
```

JSFiddle, however, pads the parent `iframe`; that's why you never technically "align" your waypoint with the viewport (`window`). Add a custom context in your waypoint's options, e.g.:

```
context: $("#waypoint").parent()
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utTU4/

Comment: That was Awesome! Accepted but I ran out of votes for the day :(